# Need a sample for WPF TreeView search with Virtualization and Load On Demand

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, treeview, lazy-loading

I need to implement search feature in WPF `TreeView`(basically I need to remember the last user selection). I have tried various approaches suggested but nothing works as `virtualization` is enabled in my `TreeView` and child nodes are loaded only when a parent node is expanded(lazy loading).

Anyone knows of a sample having these three things(Virtualization, Load-on-demand and Search) implemented together?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at [this](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/wpf/thread/5dcd22ac-9a70-4ab5-84b6-a68d2eca2759) MSDN forum thread, Bob from MS explains the problem in implementing this feature.

> the cause is the
>   `VirtualizingStackPanel` try to generate
>   a item for display, but it has a
>   generator already in your project to
>   generate the expanded items (in the
>   `OnTreeNodeExpanded` event handler). It
>   occurs conflict with two generators.
>   `VirtualizingStackPanel` can generate
>   the required item at run-time, it also
>   generate them in `BringIndexIntoView`
>   method. The code of the `StartAt` method
>   is to check the generator, if it isn't
>   null, throw the exception "Cannot call
>   `StartAt` when content generation is in
>   progress". So, the sample populates
>   all items to the bound source in the
>   `InitializeComponent()`, and let the
>   `BringIndexIntoView` method to generates
>   the container for the item.

A sample reproducing the problem is also attached in that thread.

So at present there seems to be no solution for this approach :(