# Dynamically expand treeview

Tags: wpf, vb.net, treeview, expand, treeviewitem

I am using a class as follows:

```
Class DirectoryViewItem
    Property Namee As String
    Property Iconn As BitmapImage
    Property Path As String
    Property SubNodes As New List(Of DirectoryViewItem)
End Class
```

and the xaml I used is:

```
<TreeView Name="DirectoryTreeView"
          TreeViewItem.Expanded="DirectoryTreeView_Expanded"
          Grid.Row="0">
    <TreeView.ItemTemplate >
        <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding SubNodes}">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Image Source="{Binding Iconn}"
                       Width="32" Height="32"
                       VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Left" />
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Namee}"
                           VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Left" />
            </StackPanel>
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
    </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
</TreeView>
```

The code is working fine, now I want to expand the 3 or some x node through code, and I found the solution to use something like this:

```
CType(DirectoryTreeView.Items(3), TreeViewItem).ExpandSubtree()
```

I found that the `CType` here is not `TreeViewItem` but it is my `DirectoryViewItem` type,  ... how can this be done?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Use the `TreeView.ItemContainerStyle` to bind `IsExpanded` to a property on your items.
2. Implement `ExpandSubtree` on your items (all it needs to do is set that bound property on your items to `true` recursively).

Comment: Could you please tell me in more detail, I am bit new to advanced stuff

Comment: @surpavan: It's not advanced, really. See [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4080545/546730) for an example.

Comment: That worked and I did this before seeing your link. Hehe.   Thanks for the time and for sharing the information is the best way to understand.  Many thanks.