# WPF Treeview Highlight selected item programmatically

Tags: wpf, treeview, selected

When i rebuild a WPF treeview i want to set the selected item like before the rebuild. Therefore I set the property IsSelected to true and call the method focus() for the treeviewitem. But the background of the selected item is only a pale gray color. How can achieve the standard blue background programmatically. When I click the item with the mouse the item background is blue again.

Comment: Call Focus() on treeview then IsSelected = ture on treeviewitem.

Answer (score 0):

You should use **ContainerFromItem**

For more informations access this link :

[link to containerfromitem usage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/413890/how-to-programmatically-select-an-item-in-a-wpf-treeview)