# 'Move Up Treeview' Button Selects Parent Node

Tags: xml, wpf, insert, treeview

I have a simple TreeView bound to an XMLDocument. I made some buttons which move elements up/down the tree. They work as intended but an annoying consequence is that the element that moves is deselected, and it's parent is selected. Meaning that if I want to move the element up twice, I would have to manually reselect it.

```
    private void MoveUpTV_Click (object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        XmlDataProvider XMLD = this.FindResource("xmldata") as XmlDataProvider;
        XmlElement selectedElement = (XmlElement)myTree.SelectedItem;
        selectedElement.ParentNode.InsertBefore(selectedElement, selectedElement.PreviousSibling);
        string source = XMLD.Source.LocalPath;
        XMLD.Document.Save(source);
    }
```

Can someone please point me in the right direction? I have no idea where to start. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WPF Treeview has no setter to set selectedItem. You can have an additional property 'IsSelected' for each item in the data source. Please go through [this](http://blog.quantumbitdesigns.com/2008/07/22/programmatically-selecting-an-item-in-a-treeview/) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/413890/how-to-programmatically-select-an-item-in-a-wpf-treeview) link for more info.