# C# WPF System.Windows.Controls.TreeView how to change selected node

Tags: c#, wpf, treeview

This treeview class works differently from the windows forms class. Every example I see to change selected node uses items.selectednode or nodes.selectednode.
However, I am struggling to find a method of doing this for this class:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.treeview(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: duplicate with this post : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/413890/how-to-programmatically-select-an-item-in-a-wpf-treeview

Comment: Might be duplicate. But noone seems to know how to do a rigclick select node on WPF treeview

Comment: Right-click? What do you want to exaclty and what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wanted to enable right click to popup my context menu. Could not find another solution, so here's what I did, and it works:

```
private void TreeSetup_MouseRightButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        ((TreeViewItem)sender).IsSelected = true;
        e.Handled = true;
    }

    private void TreeSetup_MouseRightButtonUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        ContextMenu PopupMenu = this.FindResource("cmButton") as ContextMenu;
        if (TreeSetup.SelectedItem != null)
        {
            PopupMenu.PlacementTarget = sender as TreeViewItem;
            PopupMenu.IsOpen = true;
        }
    }
```