# How to properly expose properties of internal controls?

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a custom control named `CustomTreeView` which contains a `TreeView`. I would like to expose the `SelectedItem` Property of the `TreeView` to users of the custom control.

For that I tried to add a new dependency property to the custom control and bind that property to the `SelectedItem` Property of the `TreeView`.

Unfortunatly I seem to be getting it wrong. Could you take a look?

**TreeView.xaml**

```
<UserControl x:Class="Fis.UI.Windows.BacNet.Views.RestructuredView.View.Controls.CustomTreeView"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             Selected="{Binding ElementName=treeView, Path=SelectedItem}">
   <TreeView x:Name="treeView"/>
</UserControl>
```

**TreeView.xaml.cs**

```
public partial class CustomTreeView : UserControl
    {
        public static readonly DependencyProperty IsSelectedProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
                                                                                             "Selected", typeof(Node),
                                                                                             typeof(TreeView)
                                                                                             );
        public Node Selected
        {
            get { return (Node)GetValue(IsSelectedProperty); }
            set { SetValue(IsSelectedProperty, value); }
        }

        public TreeView()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
```

Thanks!

Comment: The Selected property you added is part of the TreeView not the UserControl. So you can only do this: <TreeView x:Name="treeView" Selected=".." /> . Are you wanting to access the Selected property via the UserControl class?

Comment: I want users of the `Fis.UI.Windows.BacNet.Views.RestructuredView.View.Controls.TreeView` class to bind to the SelectedItem of the TreeView which is nested in this class.

For that I need to expose the SelectedItem property of the nested TreeView.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Part of your solution is [in this answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/413900/424129). It's a link-only answer with a dead link (or was -- I just improved it), but it does mention the key point.

You can't bind `TreeView.SelectedItem`. Your dependency property definition is broken in multiple ways and it should be named `SelectedItem` in accordance with standard WPF practice. Here's the usercontrol code behind, which defines the dependency property along with event handlers as a substitute for the binding.

```
public partial class CustomTreeView : UserControl
{
    public CustomTreeView()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    #region SelectedItem Property
    public Node SelectedItem
    {
        get { return (Node)GetValue(SelectedProperty); }
        set { SetValue(SelectedProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty SelectedProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register(nameof(SelectedItem), typeof(Node), typeof(CustomTreeView),
            new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(null,
                                          FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.BindsTwoWayByDefault,
                                          Selected_PropertyChanged)
            { DefaultUpdateSourceTrigger = UpdateSourceTrigger.PropertyChanged });

    protected static void Selected_PropertyChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        (d as CustomTreeView).OnSelectedChanged(e.OldValue);
    }

    private void OnSelectedChanged(object oldValue)
    {
        if (SelectedItem != treeView.SelectedItem)
        {
            var tvi = treeView.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(SelectedItem) as TreeViewItem;

            if (tvi != null)
            {
                tvi.IsSelected = true;
            }
        }
    }
    #endregion SelectedItem Property

    private void treeView_SelectedItemChanged(object sender, RoutedPropertyChangedEventArgs<object> e)
    {
        if (SelectedItem != e.NewValue)
        {
            SelectedItem = e.NewValue as Node;
        }
    }
}
```

And here's the TreeView in the UserControl XAML. I'm omitting ItemsSource and ItemTemplate as irrelevant.

```
<TreeView
    x:Name="treeView"
    SelectedItemChanged="treeView_SelectedItemChanged"
    />
```

And here's the snippet from MainWindow.xaml I used for testing it:

```
<StackPanel>
    <local:CustomTreeView x:Name="treeControl" />
    <Label 
        Content="{Binding SelectedItem.Text, ElementName=treeControl}"
        />
</StackPanel>
```

My `Node` class has a `Text` property and I'm populating the tree via the DataContext to save having to set up another dependency property for the items.